# C# Linq XML get text from multiple elements with the same name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to retrieve the product info and store it in my collection IEnumerable.  However, only the information for two products is being returned.  I tried to change my code from `Element` to `Elements` but it just threw an error.

Orderlist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListOrderItemsResponse
    xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>002-1893166-3105064</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00HUX1W1G</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>NX-CHAG-UT0Q</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>37783785306314</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Polyethylene Glycol (Peg) 200, ACS, Reagent Grade, One Quart Bottle</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>25.00</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionNote>Alliance Chemical</ConditionNote>
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>102-5169016-4946643</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00OKOU4GM</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>35-9988-XJB8</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>23504328079730</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Nitric Acid 65%, Acs, Reagent Grade, Quart(1 liter) Glass Bottle</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>48.00</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00D6JGB2S</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>DB-ZAYD-0QYZ</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>58842277149658</OrderItemId>
                <Title>HYDROCHLORIC ACID 20 Be. Technical grade-One gallon bottle</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>35.00</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>b4d81fad-7d09-4e07-b166-e5638292d56d</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>
```

Code in Main

```
path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Orderlist.xml");
file = XDocument.Load(path);

xml = file.ToString();
doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var products = Products(doc);

private static IEnumerable<Address> Products(XContainer doc)
{
    XNamespace ns = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

    return from product in doc.Descendants(ns + "ListOrderItemsResult")
           select new Address
           {
               Title = (string)product.Element(ns + "OrderItems").Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "Title"),  
               ItemPrice = (string)product.Element(ns + "OrderItems").Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ItemPrice").Element(ns + "Amount"),
               ShippingPrice = (string)product.Element(ns + "OrderItems").Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "ShippingPrice").Element(ns + "Amount"),
               Quantity = (string)product.Element(ns + "OrderItems").Element(ns + "OrderItem").Element(ns + "QuantityOrdered"),
               P_OrderId = (string)product.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId"),
           };
}


public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string ShippingPrice { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string P_OrderId { get; set; }
    public string S_OrderId { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error was thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Products method as follows.

```
return from product in doc.Descendants(ns + "ListOrderItemsResult")
    from order in product.Element(ns + "OrderItems").Elements(ns + "OrderItem")
    select new Address
    {
       Title = (string)order.Element(ns + "Title"),
       ItemPrice = (string)order.Element(ns + "ItemPrice").Element(ns + "Amount"),
       ShippingPrice = (string)order.Element(ns + "ShippingPrice").Element(ns + "Amount"),
       Quantity = (string)order.Element(ns + "QuantityOrdered"),
       P_OrderId = (string)product.Element(ns + "AmazonOrderId"),
    };
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks like what I want to do.  I'll run it when I get the chance busy at work.

Comment: Works like a charm I think I am beginning to understand how LINQ queries work hah

Answer (score 0):

You only have two ListOrderItemsResult elements in your xml, so your method should only be returning two variables.

If that's not the problem, some more information on what the errors were would be nice.

Comment: Ah! didn't notice that I need it to return three orders, going to give the @Sarathy code a run in a few. Thank you.